How to log internet connections per program?
I am looking for program or command that can log what programs connect where and when.
For example Wireshark can tell what connections were made and when but it cannot tell what program made this connection. NetHogs shows me pid, User and Program, but it does not show domains or IPs that were connected. Netstat continuous mode can show me both program and IP that was connected but Netstat does not support logging so if I don't happen to watch at my console at right time. Another problem with netstat -c is that since it read /proc/net/tcp*every second it can miss a connection if the program has already terminated by then.
Is there anything that can log all connections by programs? For example:
2024-08-12 22:12:53 /usr/bin/firefox-esr safebrowsing.googleapis.com
2024-08-12 22:14:53 "/usr/bin/wget site.com" site.com

Showing hostname instead of IP would be nice but if that is possible only with paid programs then just destination IP is also fine.
Log does not have to be in this exact format as I showed above, it was more like to demonstrate what kind of info I want to see.

netstat -atp | grep ESTAB

Problem with netstat -atp | grep ESTAB is that it does not provide continuous logging. An other problem that I learned from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/571565/how-to-continuously-monitor-pids-connecting-to-local-sockets is that netstat can miss connection entirely if program terminates in less than second.

I think your task is poorly chosen.  If you had read the Internet RFCs and STDs, you'd see that there is no userid info in the packet header. All one can do is poll/snoop for a network open going by, and deduce PID from that,  but once packetized, only the connection identifier differentiates one packet from another. No PID, Userid, Command, do not go further.

sudo tcpdump -n -i eth0 -A >file.log

@waltinator I don't think the task itself is poorly chosen. Netstat -tnp can already show process information. If that was not possible Netstat -tnp wouldn't be able to do it either. Basically it need to be something that runs in kernel mode and instead of sniffing raw packets it needs to sniff system calls so that whenever application tries to make connection, that call to kernel space would be intercepted and logged before passed on to kernel. This way you would tell what program made this call.
